# Share an EJB application into a rest service

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, netbeans, ejb

(Sorry for my english, that not my first language, but I will try to be the more clear possible).

I have to make an application based on Java EJB that can communicate with other projects through RMI for some services. But I also want to make some other services - that allow to proceed business functions on my entities - available through an REST interface. And there is where I am lost.

I created several projects on Netbeans :

- exampleApp which is composed of modules :

  - exampleApp-ejb
  - exampleApp-ear
  - exampleApp-web
- exampleAppShared (for my RMI service)

For the moment, my services look like :

```
@Stateless
public class ServicesClient implements ServicesClientLocal {

@EJB
private GestionClientLocal gestionClient;

//code refering to business functions
}
```

My RMI part functions well. But I don't know how to make my services available through an REST services. Should I create another project ?

Maybe I did search badly but I didn't find some answers here or on internet about this case...

Thanks in advance for who will take some time to answer to my (idiot) question...

Comment: Your English came out very good.  It looks like you have everything thought out properly as per your projects setup so in your web/war project you should be able to just follow this tutorial [REST Article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/REST/article.html) likely skipping to section 6 for the java examples and then scroll back up to figure out which RESTEasy jars you might need to resolve build path errors.

Comment: I imagine the REST services will use the backing beans in the EJB project - though I'm pretty sure the REST services could also just be placed in the EJB proj... erm, maybe not, hindsight I think that didnt work for me.

Comment: Well there is some options in netbeans to create some REST webservices, but I don't know which choose... and it asks for some REST resources that I have not created yet...

Comment: I dont use netbeans, I use eclipse but see if any of these search results help [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=netbeans+add+restful+web+service+to+EJB&rlz=1C1CHBF_enUS724US725&oq=netbeans+add+restful+web+service+to+EJB&aqs=chrome..69i57.13376j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).  I see a promising set of links a couple hits below on Stack Overflow which may help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found !

I just need to create with netbeans the REST webservice :

- right click on the package you want to create your webservice
- new
- RestFul webservices from patterns

Just click the first screen and then choose the name of the webservice. 
Then you can do a call of an enterprise bean.